# The time complexity answer to the question confuses me - n^(2/3)

Tags: c, recursion, time-complexity

I'm trying to figure out why the time complexity of this code is n<sup>2/3</sup>. The space complexity is log n, but I don't know how to continue the time complexity calculation (or if it's right).

```
int g2 (int n, int m)
{
  if (m >= n)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
      printf("#");
    return 1;
  }
  return 1 + g2 (n / 2, 4 * m);
}

int main (int n)
{
  return g2 (n, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as `m < n`, you perform an `O(1)` operation: making a recursive call. You halve `n` and quadruple `m`, so after `k` steps, you get

```
n(k) = n(0) * 0.5^k
m(k) = m(0) * 4^k
```

You can set them equal to each other to find that

```
n(0) / m(0) = 8^k
```

Taking the log

```
log(n(0)) - log(m(0)) = k log(8)
```

or

```
k = log_8(n(0)) - log_8(m(0))
```

On the `k`th recursion you perform `n(k)` loop iterations.

You can plug `k` back into `n(k) = n(0) * 0.5^k` to estimate the number of iterations. Let's ignore `m(0)` for now:

```
n(k) = n(0) * 0.5^log_8(n(0))
```

Taking again the log of both sides,

```
log_8(n(k)) = log_8(n(0)) + log_8(0.5) * log_8(n(0))
```

Since `log_8(0.5) = -1/3`, you get

```
log_8(n(k)) = log_8(n(0)) * (2/3)`
```

Taking the exponent again:

```
n(k) = n(0)^(2/3)
```

Since any positive exponent will overwhelm the `O(log(n))` recursion, your final complexity is indeed `O(n^(2/3))`.

---

Let's look for a moment what happens if `m(0) > 1`.

```
n(k) = n(0) * 0.5^(log_8(n(0)) - log_8(m(0)))
```

Again taking the log:

```
log_8(n(k)) = log_8(n(0)) - 1/3 * (log_8(n(0)) - log_8(m(0)))
log_8(n(k)) = log_8(n(0)^(2/3)) + log_8(m(0)^(1/3))
```

So you get

```
n(k) = n(0)^(2/3) * m(0)^(1/3)
```

Or

```
n(k) = (m n^2)^(1/3)
```

---

Quick note on corner cases in the starting conditions:

For `m > 0`:

If `n <= 0`:, `n <= m` is immediately true and the recursion terminates and there is no loop.

For `m < 0`:

If `n <= m`, the recursion terminates immediately and there is no loop. If `n > m`, `n` will converge to zero while `m` diverges, and the algorithm will run forever.

The only interesting case is where `m == 0`. Regardless of whether `n` is positive or negative, it will reach zero because of integer truncation, so the complexity depends on when it reaches 1:

```
n(0) * 0.5^k = 1
log_2(n(0)) - k = 0
```

So in this case, the runtime of the recursion is still `O(log(n))`. The loop does not run.

Comment: @interjay. Of course. About to update. Thanks for the catch

Comment: @interjay. Updated. Checks out

Comment: @interjay. I've worked out the dependency on m too for good measure.

Answer (score 2):

`m` starts at 1, and at each step `n -> n/2 and m -> m*4` until `m>n`. After `k` steps, `n_final = n/2^k` and `m_final = 4^k`. So the final value of `k` is where `n/2^k = 4^k`, or `k = log8(n)`.

When this is reached, the inner loop performs `n_final` (approximately equal to `m_final`) steps, leading to a complexity of `O(4^k) = O(4^log8(n)) = O(4^(log4(n)/log4(8))) = O(n^(1/log4(8))) = O(n^(2/3))`.

Comment: When I originally did the calculation I took a similar approach to yours, and arrived at k=log_8(n) but I did not use the assumption that m_final is equal to n_final and tried to use the n_final expression O(1/(2^k)), would that have worked the same? would you say equating n_final and m_final applicable always applicable in similar circumstances or are there caveats (first time I've seen it done)? Thank you for the solution!

Comment: @kal_elk122 The n_final expression would be `O(n/(2^k))`, which would give the same result. I chose to work with m_final because it's a simpler expression, and m_final will be no more than 8 times n_final so the big O complexity is the same.